# How to extend plot with slope of last two points in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

As shown in figure, how to make curve 1 to touch X-axis  with slope made by last bottom two points?

[image: Click on this for figure]

Code to generate above plot

```
X1 = linspace(2,3,20);
Y1 = linspace(1/1000, 1,20);
Y1Dash = flip(Y1);
X2 = linspace(14,15,30);
Y2 = linspace(1/10000, 1,30);
Y2Dash = flip(Y2);
figure;semilogy(X1, Y1Dash, "-r*");hold on;grid on;
semilogy(X2, Y2Dash, "-r*");hold off;
legend("curve1", "Curve2");
```

Comment: Giving both `curve1` and `curve2` the exact same visual appearance is confusing. Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "boundary", "extend" and "last two points"? Please [edit] the question to clarify. Drawing stuff on the image (using e.g. MS Paint) can already clarify a lot.